# How to have a UIView on top of TabBar?

Tags: cocoa-touch, xcode, uiview, uitabbar

How can I get my UIPickerView to apear on top of the TabBar?

> [Example Video](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/showflash.aspx?swf=2010-05-05_1432.swf&h=596&w=343)

This is a TabBar Application and that NIB file contain 2 views

[alt text http://cl.ly/o51/Screen_shot_2010-05-05_at_14.35.15.png](http://cl.ly/o51/Screen_shot_2010-05-05_at_14.35.15.png)

That I animate to show / hide instead of the keyboard, but the keyboard animates on top of all UIViews.

How can I accomplish this with my Custom View?

Answer (score 0):

To display the picker view, just put it in its own view. Then set that view as the textfields 'inputView` property.

When the field is selected, the view should appear in place of the keyboard.

Comment: I get what is the method to use: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/inputView But I can't figure it out to work with it :-/
BTW, this is only available for iPad (Available in iPhone OS 3.2 and later.) --> Images and screencast in my question specifies iPhone/iPod

Comment: Yep, your right, my bad. That's the trouble with jumping from OS to OS.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use use bringSubviewToFront: and sendSubviewToBack: method on your views?

Comment: it does not act upon it as the TabBar in in other controller (perhaps it's cause of that) :-(